# Why does N result in some inconsistency in this context?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, filtering

In the following, why does `N` not produce the expected decimal output, while `Round` does?

```
Cases[{ArcSec[-(3/Sqrt[5])]}, ArcSec[a_] -> {a, 2 a, N[a], Round[a,.01]}]

{{-(3/Sqrt[5]), -(6/Sqrt[5]), -(3/Sqrt[5]), -1.34}}
```

Comment: use `RuleDelayed (:>)` instead of `Rule (->)`?

Comment: with `Rule` `N[a]` is evaluated to `a` before the value of `a` gets injected: inspect `Cases[{ArcSec[-(3/Sqrt[5])]}, ArcSec[a_] -> N[a]] // Trace // Column`

Comment: Thank you, kglr! That is most helpful. Please turn that into an answer, because I think that really explains a lot.

Comment: @Raplh, posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`RuleDelayed (:>)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) instead of [`Rule (->)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) gives the desired result:

```
Cases[{ArcSec[-(3/Sqrt[5])]}, ArcSec[a_] :> {a, 2 a, N[a], Round[a, .01]}]
```

> {{-(3/Sqrt[5]), -(6/Sqrt[5]), -1.3416407864998738, -1.34}}

From [RuleDelayed >> Properties and Relations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html):

> - -> evaluates when it is first entered; :> when it is used

With `Rule` the right-hand-side `N[a]` is evaluated to `a` before replacement occurs:

```
ArcSec[a_] -> N[a]
```

> ArcSec[a_] -> a

```
ArcSec[a_] :> N[a]
```

> ArcSec[a_] :> N[a]

Compare the `Trace`s of the two cases:

```
Cases[{ArcSec[-(3/Sqrt[5])]}, ArcSec[a_] -> N[a]] // Trace // Column
```

[image]

```
Cases[{ArcSec[-(3/Sqrt[5])]}, ArcSec[a_] :> N[a]] // Trace // Column
```

[image]

For `Round`, both  `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` give the same result, because `Round[foo, .1]` does not evaluate for non-numeric input `foo` (it "evaluates" to `Round[foo, .1]`) whereas `N[foo]` evaluates to `foo`.